# Декартовое произведение Java

Tags: java, битовые-операции, множества

Здраствуйте, у меня есть клас Set для задания и получения множеств и также класс Operations с методами множеств. Все методы моего класса (типа объединение множеств, декартового произведения...) должны выполняться над полученными на предыдущем шаге битовыми строками множеств. Все методы работают хорошо, но я не знаю как переписать Декартовое произведение(cartesian Product) по типу предыдущих методов, он работает на основе обичных чисел, а не битов. Помогите переписать этот метод.
Класс Set

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Set<T> {

    private T[] set;

    public void setSet(T[] set) {
        this.set = (T[]) Arrays.stream(set).distinct().toArray();
    }

    public T[] getSet() {
        return set;
    }

    public Set(T[] array) {
        setSet(array);
    }

}
```

Класс Operations

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Operations<T> {

     // Перевод в битовую строку
     public String toBitString(Set set) {
         Object[] elements = set.getSet();
         int maxElement = Arrays.stream(elements).mapToInt(e -> (int) e).max().orElse(-1);
         int bitStringLength = maxElement + 1;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < bitStringLength; i++) {
             if (Arrays.asList(elements).contains(i)) {
                 sb.append("1");
             } else {
                 sb.append("0");
             }
         }
         return sb.toString();
     }

     // Объединение множеств
     public T[] unionSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String unionBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             unionBitString+=(bit1|bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[unionBitString.length() - unionBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < unionBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (unionBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
         return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
     }

     // Проверка есть ли элемент в массиве
     public boolean contains(T elem, Object[] array) {
         for (T element : (T[]) array) {
             if (elem.equals(element)) {
                 return true;
             }
         }
         return false;
     }

     // Сечение множеств
     public T[] intersectionSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String intersectionBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             intersectionBitString += (bit1 & bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[intersectionBitString.length() - intersectionBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < intersectionBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (intersectionBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
         return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
     }

     // Разница множеств
     public T[] differenceSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String differenceBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             differenceBitString += (bit1 & ~bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[differenceBitString.length() - differenceBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < differenceBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (differenceBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
         return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
     }
// Симметричная разница множеств
     public T[] symmetricDiffSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
         String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
         String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
         int maxLength = Math.max(bitString1.length(), bitString2.length());
         StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
         StringBuilder sb2 = новый StringBuilder();
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             if (i < bitString1.length()) {
                 sb1.append(bitString1.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb1.append("0");
             }
             if (i < bitString2.length()) {
                 sb2.append(bitString2.charAt(i));
             } else {
                 sb2.append("0");
             }
         }
         String symmetricDiffBitString = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
             int bit1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb1.charAt(i)));
             int bit2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sb2.charAt(i)));
             symmetricDiffBitString += (bit1^bit2);
         }
         Object[] elements = new Object[symmetricDiffBitString.length() - symmetricDiffBitString.replace("1", "").length()];
         int index=0;
         for (int i = 0; i < symmetricDiffBitString.length(); i++) {
             if (symmetricDiffBitString.charAt(i) == '1') {
                 elements[index++] = i;
             }
         }
         return(T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
     }

    // Декартовое произведение множеств
     public T[] cartesianProduct(Set s1, Set s2) {
         Object[] elements1 = s1.getSet();
         Object[] elements2 = s2.getSet();
         Object[] cartesianProduct = new Object[elements1.length * elements2.length];
         int index=0;
         for (Object element1 : elements1) {
             for (Object element2 : elements2) {
                 Object[] tuple = {element1, element2};
                 cartesianProduct[index++] = tuple;
             }
         }
         return (T[]) cartesianProduct;
     }
}
```

У меня есть пример для этого метода, но он работает неправильно

```
public T[] cartesianProductSets(Set s1, Set s2) {
    String bitString1 = toBitString(s1);
    String bitString2 = toBitString(s2);
    int maxLength = bitString1.length() + bitString2.length();
    String[] bitStrings = new String[maxLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < bitString1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitString2.length(); j++) {
            int index = i + j;
            String bitString = "";
            if (bitString1.charAt(i) == '1' && bitString2.charAt(j) == '1') {
                bitString = "1";
            } else {
                bitString = "0";
            }
            if (bitStrings[index] == null) {
                bitStrings[index] = bitString;
            } else {
                bitStrings[index] += bitString;
            }
        }
    }
    Object[] elements = new Object[1 << maxLength];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bitStrings.length; i++) {
        String bitString = bitStrings[i];
        if (bitString == null) {
            break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < (1 << i); j++) {
            elements[index++] = Integer.parseInt(bitString, 2);
        }
    }
    return (T[]) new Set(elements).getSet();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Декартово произведение двух множеств представляет собой массив/список пар элементов из каждого множества, поэтому непохоже, что здесь должны использоваться битовые строки.

Для простоты представим декартовое произведение как список списков, тогда можно получить результат при помощью Stream API (`Stream::flatMap`):

```java
public List<List<T>> cartesianProductSets(Set set1, Set set2) {
    return Arrays.stream(set1.getSet())
        .flatMap(s1 -> Arrays.stream(set2.getSet())
            .map(s2 -> Arrays.asList(s1, s2))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

Вариант с битовыми строками:

```java
public int[][] cartesianProductSets(Set set1, Set set2) {
    String bs1 = toBitString(set1);
    String bs2 = toBitString(set2);
    int[][] result = new int[(int) (bs1.chars().filter(c -> c == '1').count() * bs2.chars().filter(c -> c == '1').count())][2];

    for (int i = 0, r = 0, n = bs1.length(); i < n; i++) {
        if (bs1.charAt(i) == '0') continue;
        for (int j = 0, m = bs2.length(); j < m; j++) {
            if (bs2.charAt(j) == '0') continue;
            result[r++] = new int[]{i, j};
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: это условие задачи чтоб декартовое условие двух множеств по полученным битовым строкам.

Comment: Какой смысл в использовании этих строк?  А также в использовании обобщённого типа в классе `Set`, если у вас фактически можете хранить в своих множествах только целые числа?

Comment: я их перевожу в биты с помощью метода toBitString

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но вибивает ошибку в этой строке int[][] result = new int[(int) (bs1.chars().filter(c == '1').count() * bs2.chars().filter(c == '1').count())][2]; Ошыбка: Cannot resolve symbol 'c'

Comment: @VWinner, ошибка исправлена

Comment: большое спасибо)